# Convert Map key,value pairs into JSON properties of a @responseBody object

Tags: json, spring-mvc, jackson

I am wondering if this can be achieved. I have a simple spring service :

```
public @ResponseBody ResponseObject getResults(
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, @RequestBody RequestInput requestInput )
```

My ResponseObject looks like this :

```
public class ResponseObject {
    private String id;  
    private String value;
    private Map<String,String> keyValuePairs;
    .... and the regular getter/setters
```

When i add some values to keyValuePairs. I get a JSON response like this :

```
 {
        "id": "56LTY",
        "value": "56 Large Thank You",
        "keyValuePairs": {
          "origin": "Vietnam",
          "ship" : "Air"
        }
}
```

I would like to have my JSON response like so :

```
 {
        "id": "56LTY",
        "value": "56 Large Thank You",
        "origin": "Vietnam",
        "ship" : "Air"
}
```

Is this doable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnyGetter` annotation:

```
@JsonAnyGetter
public Map<String, String> getKeyValuePairs() {
    return keyValuePairs;
}
```

Comment: thanx Michal Ziober