# Create Entity for Objects of same Type inside an Object

Tags: java, oop, object, jackson

I want to represent a complex JSON Object using Lombok:

```
{
  "property1": {
    "type": "boolean",
    "value": true,
    "valueInfo": {
      "info": "Hello"
    }
  },
  "property2": {
    "type": "string",
    "value": "string234",
    "valueInfo": {
      "info": "World"
    }
  }
}
```

I was able to create an Entity when I can represent the complex object using an outer key:

```
"properties": {
  "property1": {
    "type": "boolean",
    "value": true,
    "valueInfo": {
      "info": "Hello"
    }
  },
  "property2": {
    "type": "string",
    "value": "string234",
    "valueInfo": {
      "info": "World"
    }
  }
}
```

Lombok Java Code:

```
public class ComplexObject {

@JsonProperty("properties")
@Valid
private Map<String, PropertyValueDTO> variables = null;
}

public static class PropertyValueDTO {
  @JsonProperty("type")
  private ProcessVariableTypeEnum type;

  @JsonProperty("value")
  private String value;

  @JsonProperty("valueInfo")
  @Valid
  private Map<String, Object> valueInfo = null;

}
```

Is it possible to represent `PropertyValueDTO` from a base entity class without the need for key (`properties`)?

Comment: Map<String, PropertyValueDTO> already does what you need I guess.

Comment: Means do you need List of PropertyValueDTO in ComplexObject  ?

Comment: Take a look at [JsonAnyGetter](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.11/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonAnyGetter.html) annotation. And take a look on these answers: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61337816/51591) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55687330/51591)